# C# script Engine in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

i have a silverlight 5 application in that i have to execute C# code on a button click event,

1. upload or write c# file find out all the methods and property from Uploaded file or writen Code
2. Select Property for set values
3. Select a method for execute.

Please suggest me how can i execute c# code in Silverlight,

i have try some of code in desktop application but that not work in silverlight because of not able to add referenced DLL in silverlight

Comment: You need to execute user entered code?

Comment: Silverlight apps are hosted in a sandbox with a ripped CLR. Don't expect any desktop code to run, as that requires a full CLR and no sandbox.

Comment: Yes you are right Mason, i have to execute user entered code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

You will need to compile the Code files given to you using the methods described above and then execute the methods found using reflection.

However I am not sure you can do this using Silverlight, as the .NET libries in Silverlight are lightweight for the Enviroment it runs in.